# Does hypoxia take effect more quickly if an aircraft is flying at a greater height?

Tags: medical, hypoxia

In case of depressurization, will the effects of hypoxia be more rapid the greater height the aircraft flies?

Comment: Related: [How long does it take for pilots to become unconscious after an uncontrolled depressurization at FL 340?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44748/how-long-does-it-take-for-pilots-to-become-unconscious-after-an-uncontrolled-dep)

Comment: Also [Time of Useful Consciousness (TUC)](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Time_of_Useful_Consciousness) at SKYbrary

Comment: I'm not sure what the root confusion might be...  If you know what hypoxia actually is, doesn't the question answer itself?

Comment: I did a chamber ride to 25000 once as part of a skydiver high alt cert course.  It was just to experience and become aware of your onset symptoms. I lasted about 4ish min, then tunnel vision set in (peripheral vision greyed out), then at maybe about 5 min the euphoria came on, in a gush that surprised me. I reconnected my mask and the symptoms vanished after the first or second breath. Buddy who was a smoker was well into euphoria stage and cackling like he was on laughing gas by 3-4 minutes.  Weirdly you are drawing shapes and you know they are lopsided, but you think they are fine like that.

Answer (score 3):

The higher the altitude at which the plane depressurizes, the quicker the onset of hypoxia- and the less time the pilot has to get his or her oxygen mask on before passing out.

Comment: The "partial pressure" is too low.  Problem is, you don't know it when just sitting there.  You can't tell unless you are under exertion.  You don't realize there is even a problem until you enter the euphoria stage, and then it's too late unless there is someone else to intervene.